# Assertion failed: `secret` format does not match expected client secret formatting in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, payment-method

**Implementation of first API**
Stripe has three APIs and I've implemented these three APIs properly which showing their result properly but I have issue while opening the payment sheet, Half payment sheet is opened and then app crashed.

```
func postRequestForCustomer() {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            Constants.authorization: Constants.bearer
        ]
        AF.request(Constants.stripeBaseURL + Constants.customers, method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .response { [self] response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    if let jsonData = value {
                        do {
                            let json = try JSON(data: jsonData)
                            if let customerId = json["id"].string {
                                postRequestForEphemeralKey(customerID: customerId)
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print("Error parsing JSON for customer creation: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Unexpected response format for customer creation")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Customer Creation Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
    }
```

**Implementation of second API**

```
func postRequestForEphemeralKey(customerID: String) {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            Constants.authorization: Constants.bearer,
            Constants.stripe_Version: Constants.stripe_Version_date
        ]
        let params: [String: Any] = [
            Constants.Params.customer: customerID
        ]
        AF.request(Constants.stripeBaseURL + Constants.ephemeral_keys, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .response { [self] response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    if let jsonData = value {
                        print("Ephemeral Key Response: \(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")")
                        postRequestForPayment(customerID: customerID, amount: 10000)
                    } else {
                        print("Unexpected response format for ephemeral key")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    if let data = response.data, let errorMessage = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print("Ephemeral Key Error: \(errorMessage)")
                    } else {
                        print("Ephemeral Key Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

**Implementation of third API**

```
func postRequestForPayment(customerID: String, amount: Int) {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            Constants.authorization: Constants.bearer,
        ]

        let params: [String: Any] = [
            Constants.Params.customer: customerID,
            Constants.Params.amount: amount,
            Constants.Params.currency: Constants.Params.usd
        ]

        AF.request(Constants.stripeBaseURL + Constants.payment_intents, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .response { [self] response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    if let jsonData = value {
                        do {
                            let json = try JSON(data: jsonData)
                            if let ephKeyID = json["id"].string {
                                openPaymentSheet()
                                print("Ephemeral Key ID: \(ephKeyID)")
                            } else {
                                print("Ephemeral Key ID not found in response")
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print("Error parsing JSON for ephemeral key: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Unexpected response format for ephemeral key")
                    }

                case .failure(let error):
                    if let data = response.data, let errorMessage = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print("Ephemeral Key Error: \(errorMessage)")
                    } else {
                        print("Ephemeral Key Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

**Opening the payment sheet**

```
func openPaymentSheet() {
        if let paymentSheet = paymentSheet {
            paymentSheet.present(from: self) { paymentResult in
                // MARK: Handle the payment result
                switch paymentResult {
                case .completed:
                    print("Your order is confirmed")
                case .canceled:
                    print("Canceled!")
                case .failed(let error):
                    print("Payment failed: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Payment sheet is nil. Check the configuration.")
        }
    }
```

**Here is the viewDidLoad method**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        xibRegister()
        setUI()
        let configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration()
        paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(paymentIntentClientSecret: Constants.secret_Key, configuration: configuration)
    }
```

I've issue to open the payment sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing in your Stripe secret key (format would be `sk_test_123`) when initializing PaymentSheet? If so, that would explain the error you're getting.

The `paymentIntentClientSecret` param expects a Payment Intent `client_secret` (format would be `pi_xxx_secret_yyy`), which is not the same as your account-wide secret key. You need to be creating a Payment Intent through Stripe's API, and use the `client_secret` [value](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret) you get back after creation to correctly set up Payment Sheet.  They talk about all of this in their "Accept a Payment" docs [here](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&ui=payment-sheet)